# A Button with a border and background as drawable

Tags: android, button, drawable, shapes

ALl I can find is button with color as background

```
<solid android:color="@android:color/
```

How can you have a Button with both a border color and a background as an image or drawable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do many things:
for adding an image to background one way is adding this line in the xml layout file for that button:

```
android:background="@drawable/image"
```

`image` is your background picture's name and it is copied to `drawable` folder.

Here is a good and complete tuatorial :

https://101apps.co.za/articles/android-buttons-tutorial.html